# href with nested image server equivalent

Tags: asp.net, html

I have the following markup on my page

```
<a href="some.aspx">
  <img src=""><strong>Text</strong>
</a>
```

I need to change to the server behaviour , what can be asp.net server equivalent of the following markup ?

Comment: add the runat="server" attribute in anchor as well as img tag.

Comment: @RaviJain Why don't you answer the question? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not try doing it this way?

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hplSomeLink" NavigateUrl="some.aspx" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/Images/someimage.png"></HyperLink>
```

Seems a bit neater and will render the same as:

```
<a href="some.aspx">
    <img src="/App_Themes/Default/Images/someimage.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add the runat="server" and id attribute in anchor as well as img tag.
So it should look like :

```
<a href="some.aspx" runat="server" id="anchor_id" >
  <img src="" runat="server" id="img_id" /><strong>Text</strong>
</a>
```

Programatically you can access these elements by their id , like :

```
{
    anchor_id.innerHTML = "........";
}
```